# How to store a Color in an unsigned char?

Tags: c++, image, opengl, colors, soil

I use openGL´s SOIL to load images and SOIL_load_image() returns an unsigned char*, which is then used by openGL to color all the width*height pixels.

I would like to be able to pass my own unsigned char* to represent one single color. How do I represent color in a string/char*?

This is what I am thinking about:

```
GLuint createTextureID(std::string texturePath) {

    int width, height;
    GLuint texID = 0;
    unsigned char* texData = nullptr;

    //currently, all my file paths begin with "..//"
    if (texturePath.at(0) != '.')
    {
        texData = texturePath.c_str();
        width = 1;
        height = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        texData = SOIL_load_image(texturePath.c_str(), &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGBA);
    }

    //UPLOAD texData TO OPENGL
}
```

Comment: It probably is a pointer to an unsigned char array with three (RGB) or four (RGBA) entries. You'll have to find out the order of the color channels in the array.

Comment: How do i do that? when i check the pointer to the data with a breakpoint it only contains cryptic characters ("ÃÄ¾ÿª«¥ÿŸ šÿ•–ÿ....")

Comment: In C and C++ `unsigned char` is essentially an unsigned byte. Therefore the pointer you have points to a memory region of bytes. The layout of pixels on that buffer varies from format to format. For example, Windows bitmaps are stored on (1-byte Blue, 1-byte Green, 1-Byte Red) components aligned on a multiple of 4 line of pixels.

Comment: could you be a little bit more explicit? what do you mean with "es"?

Comment: Load three bitmaps, one each of pure red, pure green, and pure blue. As you do, look at the integer values in the `char`s its pointer leads to. Chances are good that you'll see patterns of `255, 0, 0`, `0, 0, 255`, and `0, 255, 0`. Look at which color gives a 255 and which position, and you'll know the order in which it expects the colors.

Comment: thanks, it finally works. dealing with strings and char* is somewhat of a pain, i think i need a recap on that